# How to copy file from one path to another if path exist only

Tags: python, shutil

I am searching over internet but not getting

if my source and destination path exist then only copy
source file : abc.csv to destination path

```
import shutil 

shutil.copyfile("/demo/abc.csv" "/dummy/")
```

If destination path does not exist it is creating I don't want it to happen

if both path exist then only copy abc.csv from one path to another path

Comment: Take a look at os.path.* for some useful utility functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of this question is that the source is a file and the target is a directory and furthermore that the copy should only be attempted if the source exists (as a plain file) and the target exists (as a directory). If that's the case then:

```
import os
import shutil

def safe_copy(source_file, target_directory):
  if os.path.isfile(source_file) and os.path.isdir(target_directory):
      shutil.copyfile(source_file, os.path.join(target_directory, os.path.basename(source_file)))
```

Given a source file /home/test.txt and a target directory /foo then if /home/test.txt exists and /foo is an existing directory then the copy will take place (if permitted) resulting in /foo/test.txt either being created or overwritten

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.isdir()` to check if a directory exists.

```py
destination_dir = ""
file_name = ""
if os.path.isdir(destination_dir):
    try:
        path = os.path.join(destination_dir, file_name)
        shutil.copyfile("/demo/abc.csv", path)
    except:
        # handle error
```

Comment: shutil.copyfile() raises IsADirectoryError if the target is a directory

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer os.path.join() for reliable construction of the target? If destination_dir does not end with an appropriate directory separator this will not work

Comment: @LancelotduLac fair enough, added a `try/except` block